# Multiple Column Index vs Multiple Indexes

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following table in a MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE `secondary_images` (
  `imgId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `primaryId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `view` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imgURL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imgDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imgId`),
  KEY `primaryId` (`primaryId`),
  KEY `imgDate` (`imgDate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

The SQL will be the following:

```
SELECT imgURL, view FROM secondary_images 
WHERE primaryId={$imgId} ORDER BY imgDate DESC
```

As you can see I made both the `primaryId` and `imgDate`, Index Keys. My thinking behind that was because the `WHERE` clause queries results using the `primaryId`, and the `ORDER` clause  uses `imgDate`.

My question is, would it be better to use Multiple Indexes as I am right now? Or should I a Multiple Column Index (something I don't understand all too well at the moment)?

**This is what I get from EXPLAIN:**

```
id = 1   
select_type = simple      
table = secondary_images         
type = ref
possible_keys = primaryId
key = primaryId
key_len = 5
ref = const
rows = 1
extra = Using where; Using filesort
```

**NOTE:** This is not using a Multiple Column Index, it is the result from using the above table description.

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAIN for the select? :)

Comment: Keep in mind that indeces are not free.  If you have multiple indeces, that means on each insert or update, each index needs to be updated.  You need to weigh the performance hit of those updates to the performance improvement you'll see on retrieval.

Comment: Also remember that if you have a column that has the same value in many rows, indexes might actually make performance worse.

Comment: @Marvo - This database is used purely for retrieval. I will be the only person placing data in the database. I think that solves any problems concerning what you mentioned?

Comment: @Poodlehat - I *do* actually have what you mention. The `primaryId` is not unique to each row. In fact, there will often be the same `primaryId` for up to 10 entries. That will cause a problem you think?

Comment: @Konerak - I'm sorry, what are you asking me to post?

Comment: @stef: aha! You're about to learn something very useful. Do the SELECT query, but add the `explain` keyword before it: `explain SELECT imgURL, view FROM secondary_images 
WHERE primaryId={$imgId} ORDER BY imgDate DESC`. Read [Optimizing Queries With Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html).

Comment: @Konerak - ooooh I've never heard of that! I'll give it a go!

Comment: @stefmikhail Wasn't implying there were problems with multiple indexes.  Just something you need to consider.

Comment: It really depends on the size of your table. Something to look out for is to run the EXPLAIN and see if MySQL is actually using your index or not. It might decide to not use it if there are many duplicates. I have a book that calls this the "scan vs seek" problem. Basically, you would do something like `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT primaryId) FROM secondary_images` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM secondary_images` and calculate the ratio. The larger the number, the higher the "selectivity". If the number is too low, it won't make a useful index.

Comment: @Marvo - Good to know for the future. Thanks.

Comment: @Konerak - And what, do I `echo` something after the query with explain at the beginning?

Comment: @Poodlehat - I'm only slightly following what you're saying. Have a useful link that might explain more? I would ask you to write me a detailed email on the subject, but I think a link would be easier on you ;)

Comment: @stefmikhail: eh, just execute the explain. Use a MySQL client (phpmyadmin, console, mysql query browser, toad...) and see?

Comment: @Konerak - I found a way to print it on my page in an array. But I have no idea what it means. Any chance you could take a quick look and explain? I'll post it in my question above.

Comment: @stefmikhail look at slide #12 http://joinfu.com/presentations/index_coding_optimization.pdf

Comment: @Poodlehat - Thanks for all the information, and I will, indeed read it. But in your opinion, should I, or should I not, switch from having 2 indexes, to having 1 multiple column index?

Comment: I think I've been convinced to make the switch.

Comment: [It's actually the most common question about indexing at all...](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/index-merge-performance?dbtype=mysql) and [How multi-column indexes (concatenated indexes) work](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys)

Comment: @Poodlehat - And lastly (I promise), could you *please* post the sql code to make the switch? I'm still not that apt when it comes to sql. :)

Comment: something like `ALTER TABLE secondary_images DROP INDEX primaryId, DROP INDEX imgDate, ADD INDEX IdNDate (imgId DESC, primaryId ASC) ;` should do the trick.

Comment: @Poodlehat - Thanks a bunch. Wish you posted an answer so I could give you props!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use a multi-column index on (primaryId, imgDate) so that MySQL is able to use it for selecting the rows and sorting.

If all the columns used for sorting are not in the index used for selection, MySQL uses the "*filesort*" strategy, which consists of sorting all rows (in memory if there is not too much rows; on disk else).

If all columns used for sorting are in the index, MySQL uses the index to get the rows order (with some restrictions).

MySQL uses a tree structure for the indexes. This allows to access keys in order directly without sorting.

A multi-column index is basically an index of the concatenation of the columns. This allows MySQL to find the first row matching `primaryId={$imgId}`, and then access all the other rows directly in the right order.

With a single-row index on `primaryId`, MySQL can find all the rows matching `primaryId={$imgId}`, but it will find the rows in no particular order; so it will have to sort them after that.

See [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html) and [ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: I don't understand why - it is comparing one column to another, not two columns simultaneously to two other columns. Can you explain?

Comment: @arnaud576875 - Thanks very much! Any chance you could give me a brief explanation of why that is best choice in this situation? Also, how would I go about changing my current table using `SQL` to use a multi-column index on `(primaryId, imgDate)`?

Comment: @arnaud576875 - Excellent explanation. Curious however; the `primaryId` is not unique. Up to ten different entires may have the same `primaryId`. Does this change anything?

Answer (score 15):

Your explain looks like this:

```
[id] => 1 
[select_type] => SIMPLE 
[table] => secondary_images 
[type] => ref 
[possible_keys] => primaryId 
[key] => primaryId 
[key_len] => 5 
[ref] => const 
[rows] => 1 
[Extra] => Using where; Using filesort
```

Let's walk through it.

```
[id] => 1
```

Means we're talking about the first table. You're only calling one table in your statement.

```
[select_type] => SIMPLE
```

We're doing a simple SELECT.

```
[table] => secondary_images
```

The table name in question.

```
[type] => ref
```

The select type, most important for joins.

```
[possible_keys] => primaryId
```

This is **an important field**: it shows which keys can possibly be used to aid the query in executing faster. In this case, only your primary key is deemed useful.

```
[key] => primaryId
```

This is **an important field**: it shows which key(s) finally were used. In this case, the primary key.

```
[key_len] => 5 
[ref] => const 
[rows] => 1
```

Guesssing the number of rows examined by the query.

```
[Extra] => Using where; Using filesort
```

The **most important field** imho.
 - Using where: You are using a where-statement. Quite ok.
 - Using filesort: the result of your query is so big, it can't be
   sorted in memory. MySQL has to write it to a file, sort the file, and
   then output. This means disk access and will slow down everything.
   Adding an index that can aid the sorting often helps, but solving
   "using filesort" is a chapter on its own.

Comment: Wow, wow wow. Thank you very much for that. So much easier to understand. So how can I use this information to decide if a multiple index key is the way to go? I won't ask you to get into the filesort issue as you yourself said that's another problem entirely, but would switching to a multiple index key help with this?

Comment: You should **first** read up about explain. The MySQL site is a great place to start, and 'High Performance MySQL' is the best MySQL book I ever read. Then, understand that it very much depends on your table, the storage engine, your configuration (cache sizes and so), and the data in the table. So, the best way to test: copy the table, and add the desired index on the copy. Then, compare the explains. This is why you need to understand explain :)

Comment: Thanks again. Much appreciated. I'll pick up that book.

Comment: I usually prefer (free) internet resources (googleable, ctrl-f, bookmarks) over dead trees, but that book is great. A few of the authors have very interesting blogs too, their site is [percona.com](http://www.percona.com/about-us/blogs/)

Comment: I've never checked out those internet resources. Thanks for the links. I do have several apps for my iPhone which are O'Reilly Media books on MySQL. I should read more of them.

Comment: Important correction: "Using filesort" does NOT necessarily mean it has to write to disk. It can also do it in memory if it doesn't exceed the sort buffer size.

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower does the appearance of `using filesort` imply query inefficiency? I have queries that return a few ~16Kb from a table of ~30 rows but they always use filesort....

Comment: In general, yes, using filesort means it's using more resources. However, for such a small data set as yours, you won't see any difference. For differences in performance you'd need a lot more data involved.