# sql performance advice - selecting null column takes too long on millions of records

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have the following output of a query, which outputs 5.8 million rows:

[image: the output is 5.8 million rows]

the query

```
SELECT b.BoardingZones as a, c.BoardingZones as b  FROM gocard.journey_brisbane_transport as a
LEFT JOIN gocard.journey_brisbane_transport_boarding_stop_zones as b
ON a.Boarding_Stop = b.Boarding_Stop
LEFT JOIN gocard.journey_brisbane_transport_boarding_stop_zones as c
ON a.Alighting_Stop = c.Boarding_Stop
```

I would like to output the columns a and b which contain no 'null' values.
like this:

[image]

I have tried to run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT b.BoardingZones as a, c.BoardingZones as b  FROM gocard.journey_brisbane_transport as a
LEFT JOIN gocard.journey_brisbane_transport_boarding_stop_zones as b
ON a.Boarding_Stop = b.Boarding_Stop
LEFT JOIN gocard.journey_brisbane_transport_boarding_stop_zones as c
ON a.Alighting_Stop = c.Boarding_Stop) as g
WHERE g.a IS NOT NULL
and g.b is NOT NULL
```

This query doesn't perform well at all. and takes hours to complete.
I am new to database desgin. What approach can be used to speed up this query? maybe an index?

the problem is, that can index's be performed on results of an sql, or just on a table?

thanks 
daniel

Comment: Yes, an index should help, and `NULL` value can be indexed in MySQL.

Comment: hey @TimBiegeleisen, which table do I perform the index on?

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273998/mysql-beginner-multiple-column-index).  You're probably OK just creating two separate indices on the `a` and `b` columns.

Comment: if you don't want `NULL` values why are you you using `LEFT JOIN`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you need to keep in mind:
use Left/Right joins in cases you do want NULLs in your result if not then use regular join which works faster(usually).

The second thing is that you should add Indexes but know that if you have a lot of update/insert/delete operations it may slow things down a little (if you recive 5.8M rows I think you have a lot of inserts all the time but nonetheless I think it is a good trade-off)

I strongley advise to use regular join because in mysql you can index NULLs but in other DBs you cannot so if you'll decide to change DB it would be much easier(speaking from personal mistakes).